# Run one function on different CPUs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I have one machine with two CPUs, and each CPU has different number of cores. I have one function in my python code. How can I run this function on each of the CPUs?

In this case, I need to run function two times because I have two CPUs.

I want this because I want to compare the performance of different CPU.
This can be part of code. Please let me know if the code it not written in correct way.

```
import multiprocessing

def my_function():
    print ("This Function needs high computation")
    # Add code of function

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
jobs = []
for j in range(2): #how can I run function depends on the number of CPUs?
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = my_function)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

I have read many posts, but have not found a suitable answer for my problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using, I don't know the answer but think it will make a difference

Comment: I'm pretty sure `multiprocessing.Process` runs functions in seperate cores already?

Comment: This is not really a Python question; it's an OS question.  You need to research how to run on a specified core for your operating system and platform.  *Then* you can likely execute your script using the appropriate shell command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172101/designate-specific-cpu-for-a-process-python-multiprocessing

Comment: @JeffUK  I am using Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 1):

The `concurrent` package handles the allocation of resources in an easy way, so that you don't have to specify any particular process/thread IDs, something that is OS-specific anyway.

If you want to run a function using either multiple processes or multiple threads, you can have a class that does it for you:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import Generator

class ConcurrentExecutor:
    @staticmethod
    def _concurrent_execution(executor, func, values):
        with executor() as ex:
            if isinstance(values, Generator):
                return list(ex.map(lambda args: func(*args), values))
            return list(ex.map(func, values))

    @staticmethod
    def concurrent_process_execution(func, values):
        return ConcurrentExecutor._concurrent_execution(
            ProcessPoolExecutor, func, values,
        )

    @staticmethod
    def concurrent_thread_execution(func, values):
        return ConcurrentExecutor._concurrent_execution(
            ThreadPoolExecutor, func, values,
        )
```

Then you can execute any function with it, even with arguments. If it's a single argument-function:

```py
from concurrency import ConcurrentExecutor as concex

# Single argument function that prints the input
def single_arg_func(arg):
    print(arg)

# Dummy list of 5 different input values
n_values = 5
arg_values = [x for x in range(n_values)]

# We want to run the function concurrently for each value in values
concex.concurrent_thread_execution(single_arg_func, arg_values)
```

Or with multiple arguments:

```py
from concurrency import ConcurrentExecutor as concex

# Multi argument function that prints the input
def multi_arg_func(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

# Dummy list of 5 different input values per argument
n_values = 5
arg1_values = [x for x in range(n_values)]
arg2_values = [2*x for x in range(n_values)]

# Create a generator of combinations of values for the 2 arguments
args_values = ((arg1_values[i], arg2_values[i]) for i in range(n_values))

# We want to run the function concurrently for each value combination
concex.concurrent_thread_execution(multi_arg_func, args_values)
```