# Python Multiprocessing - Executing multiple programs utilizing different core counts

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to execute multiple programs in parallel on physical cores, which each use a different number of cores.
Let's say I have the following programs:
`p1.exe` (using 1 core), `p2.exe` (using 2 cores), `p4.exe` (4 cores), and `p8.exe` (8 cores)

I currently call these in serial using `subprocess.Popen`, but want to execute p1, p2 and p4 parallel and then p8, when using an 8 core machine. While executing p1, p2 and p4, I don't want p4 to run on e.g. cores 0, 1, 2, 3 while p2 or p1 use and of those.

Does pythons multiprocessing have an option to specify which cores to use, or is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Designate specific CPU for a process - python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172101/designate-specific-cpu-for-a-process-python-multiprocessing)

Comment: @AhmedAEK it's a good start, but I still need to find the indexes where the physical cores are located. I only found how to get the number of physical cores, but when specifying which cores to use, I still need to know which of them are actual physical ones