# Parallel I/O with POSIX threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, io, pthreads, posix

Is there a simple way in the C language, using POSIX threads, to send all the file output of a program (e.g. `fprintf...`) to a cpu core other than the one that is executing the code?  I mean in such a way that the code keeps on flowing and does not need to wait for the file to have been written to continue.

My program does numerical integration and at every step of integration writes data to a file.

Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways, do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I would like to see an example of what libraries I have to include, and what is the command to send the output to another core. I'm very new in multihreading

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information regarding your question on how to set a particular thread on a particular core from: 
[how to set CPU affinity of a particular pthread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread)

However setting the 2 thread(writer thread and other thread) on different core does not mean that you does not require to synchronize between these threads. You would have to synchronize between these two threads. By setting 2 threads on different core may give you the better througput(but it depends on many other factor).

Comment: You don't have to sync using two threads using a queue or two.

Comment: @self, then how would writer thread would know that it has received the data to be written into the file.

Comment: You use a circular queue; you don't even need atomic vars.

Comment: @self That circular queue...is that a place where my data goes before being printed?

Comment: @JanusGowda Yes, search the phrase online.

Comment: @self Ok, sorry. I'm not a computer person. I'm a mathematician and need to improve my code.