# Are pthread.h threads running in just one core

Tags: c, multithreading, cpu-cores

I want to know whether threads created using `pthread.h`library are using one core, or they are running in multiple cores.

Comment: They'll run on as many cores as the OS allows them to. That can be none, one, ..., or even 64 if you have a server CPU.

Comment: Whatever the underlying (POSIX thread compatible) OS chooses.

Comment: @Zeta or not the OS at all, when the pthread implementation is a userspace implementation, which is also possible

Comment: What the above comments are telling you is that `pthreads` is an API.  In order to get the answer you are looking for, you'll have to identify a specific _implementation_ of the pthreads API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newly created thread has no affinity, and will be shuffled around the process as deemed best by the system.

If you need to pin it to a specific core, [this answer provides details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1407786/1790644) for setting affinity to a specific pthread.

Comment: This answer is only correct for specific environments, i.e. common linux distributions. pthreads can of course be implemented for example as userspace threads, where this is not correct.