# How seastar invoke codes on different cpus?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, smp

I am currently working with seastart framework, 
and find it claims that seastart can submit task to different cpus.

Seastar claims that it shares nothing between different coers.

[image]

So I think seastar binds differnet threads to different cpus,
 and make different tasks submited to different background threads(called engine、container or something).

How seastar achieve this, use `pthread_setaffinity_np` ?

But before task submitted, codes still work on random thread? Just key resources like network socket or storages are distributed to different cpus by coding using `smp::submit_to` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Seastar until now and the picture looks horribly inefficient. As is confirmed by [benchmarks](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/issues/522). It is way more efficient to have a single stack per thread, since the top of the stack is always "hot" (cached in L1).

Anyway, yes, to pin a thread to a core you can use platform-specific API. In case of POSIX that would be [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread):

```
cpu_set_t cpuset;
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(core, &cpuset); // core number starts from 0
int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(myThread.native_handle(), (cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
```

Or [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask) on Windows:

```
DWORD_PTR mask = (DWORD_PTR) (1 << core); // core number starts from 0
auto rc = SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), mask);
```